# but for (noun) vs. With no (noun)

Tags: difference

What's the difference between them? For example,

> But for language, there would be no thought.

Can this be replaced like the following sentence?

> With no language, there would be no thought.

Also, can they be rewritten using "without"?

Comment: The second one sounds a bit more natural to me and using _without_ would be fine.

Comment: Oh the first example sentence is quoted from my textbook lol

Comment: The first example is OK, it is just that the second sounded a bit more natural. Probably some other speakers would think the opposite.

Comment: Both mean the same. _But for_  (meaning _if it was not for_, so _if [it] didn't exist_) is a bit more 'literary' in flavour.

Comment: I got it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But for language, there would be no thought.

This sentence is voluntarily formal, probably claiming to sound like an axiom, or a general truth. I do like its expression, especially if used in the appropriate context.

In spoken language, however, one would more naturally say the second. If you decide to use *without* be sure to use *any* after it.

> Without ***any*** language, there would be no thought.

In conclusion, if you are more concerned about the natural use of English, your second version of the sentence [prevails](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but%20for%2C%20with%20no%2C%20without%20any&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%20any%3B%2Cc0).